# multiple pages with C# Web browser control

Tags: c#-3.0, webbrowser-control

I am trying to download HTML content from any URL through webbrowser control in C#.net.
I choose webrowser to handle Javascript issues. I am using webbrowser control without placing
it on the form. It works great for one url, but when I call it for multiple urls I am unable
to download the page.

Here is the code

```
 GetWebpage()
 {
     System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser wb = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();


                wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);

                wb.Navigate(sURI, false);  


                bDocumentLoaded = false;

                while (!bDocumentLoaded) 
                {
                    Application.DoEvents(); 
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
                sHTML = wb.DocumentText;

                bDocumentLoaded = false;  

  }
```

Event:

```
private void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {


            System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser1;         
            webBrowser1 = sender as WebBrowser;

            string strTit = webBrowser1.DocumentTitle;
            string str = webBrowser1.DocumentText;

            bDocumentLoaded = true; 

        }
```

Cheers,
Karthik

Comment: Is the issue that the application hangs while(!bDocumentLoaded) ? I have run into the same issue and I'm curious what others are doing to make the WebBrowser control work synchronously

Answer (score 0):

You can use webclient object to fetch data from some url.

Try using Downloading String

```
 public static void DownloadString (string address)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient ();
        string reply = client.DownloadString (address);

        Console.WriteLine (reply);
    }
```

You can also use ASYC method of same downloading string.

I think your problem is that some sites are detecting specific browsertype and then they are returning HTML

Try setting the `HeaderProperty` of `WebClient Object` this is a list of `HttpWebRequest` Object

For Example

myWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

Modify the useragent of HTTPWEBRequest then add to headers.
HTTPWEBRequest.UserAgent=".NET Framework Test Client";

You can check more information about this in [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.headers.aspx)

Comment: I have jus tried webclient Object, It works great but has some pages are blocked by Javascript issues.

Answer (score 0):

I might recommend using the mshtml and SHDocVW libraries and using approach found in the answer here:

[Unable to to locate and click a submit button using mshtml.HTMLInputElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088120/unable-to-to-locate-and-click-a-submit-button-using-mshtml-htmlinputelement)